# How to erase particular portion without effecting other part in UIImageView?

Tags: iphone, drawing, uiimage

I have one UIView with an UIImageview in which i have an image downloaded from web service. Now i try to draw with drawRect: in it. I want to erase part of my drawing same as like eraser without effecting background image downloaded from web service.
So how can i do that?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you simply want to "replace" part of the UIImageView with rendered primitives, rather than editing the image data, just place a UIView with a [UIColor clearColor] background color on top of the UIImageView and draw into that overlay UIView with a non-transparent color.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your looking at it the right way.

How I would do this is:

1) get the bitmap in the UIImageView

2) change the pixels/areas that you want to change

3) set the altered bitmap in your view